# Sidebar appears above content (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i just created a new sidebar for my blog, but it keeps appearing on the top of the content instead of being aligned to the left, with the posts wraping around it. webpage is as follows: http://www.joblistuae.com/job/mazrui-holdings-company-39-job-in-abu-dhabi-for-finance-manager-investments-2/

Css code used in stylesheet is:

```
#sidebar-2 {
float: left;
padding: 5% 0 3%;
margin-right: 30px;
width: 138px;
}

.sidebar-none #sidebar-2 {
display: none;
}

#content {
width: 528px;
}`
```

Please advice, thanks in advance

Comment: The CSS rules are not being applied. Are you sure you have added them in the right place? Inspect the element using Web Developer tools to check that.

Comment: how do i do that please? thank you

Comment: To which file have you added the above given CSS code?

Comment: to stlyle.css thank you